# ListFragment, not displaying data

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to get my ListFragment to display in my view, however I am having endless problems with this code and can't get it to display the results of my parser. I believe it's most likely to be a problem with my xml file, I am receiving no errors in my code, it just doesn't display the ListView.

activity_main.xml

```
}

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        class="com.example.CourseList">

    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

list_layout.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/course"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="36sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/room"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/course"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/course"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/course"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/building"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/room"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/room"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/room"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: first, you don't have any ListView with id android.R.id.list.
second, you have not added your Fragment to Activity...

Comment: Apologies for the android.R.id.list, I chanegd the name to get it ready for stackoverflow

Comment: here R.layout.courselist_layout does not contain any ListView with id android.R.id.list. then how can you say


listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);


in onCreateView() of Fragment?

Comment: So should it be R.layout.activity_main.xml instead? Or should I move the ListView there?

Comment: what do you mean by class="com.example.CourseList" for ListView? is your IDE not showing any error?

Comment: It was included in a tutorial I followed earlier, I don't get any IDE errors with that or at all currently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first change id if ListView.

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list" >
</ListView>
```

in Fragment,

```
   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,
                container, false);
        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        return rootView;
    }
```

this should be your Activity layout (R.layout.activity_layout)

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

</FrameLayout>
```

in your Activity ,

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout, new YourFragment()).commit();
}
```

you can write your Adapter like

```
class TimetableAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Timetable> records;
            private final LayoutInflater inflater;

    public TimetableAdapter(Context context, List<Timetable> records) {
        this.context = context;
        this.records = new ArrayList<Timetable>(records);
                    infalter  = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView course;
        TextView room;
        TextView building;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        Timetable rowItem = getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.courselist_layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.course = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.course);
            holder.room = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.room);
            holder.building = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.building);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.course.setText(rowItem.getCourse());
        holder.room.setText(rowItem.getRoom());
        holder.building.setText(rowItem.getBuilding());

        return convertView;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return records.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return records.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
}
```

and write

```
    @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    int num = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
    records = dao.getAllRecords();
    mAdapter = new TimetableAdapter(getActivity(),  records);
    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Comment: So create a new xml file Activity_layout?

Comment: don't delete activity_main, use it onCreateView() of Fragmnet and use R.layout.activity_layout(see FrameLayout above) in Activity

Comment: Gotcha, I'll give that a go

Comment: and do some analysis based on this answer and let me know if any problem exists...

Comment: When adding your three override method at the end, I don't get much but errors, what were you wanting to do with them?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43439/discussion-between-gopal-rao-and-kom)

Comment: 4 years later...just want to point out Google's document specifically pointed out NOT to call setAdapter from listview: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to be calling `onViewCreated`. Try changing this line of code:

```
     @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        int num = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
        records = dao.getAllRecords();
        mAdapter = new TimetableAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.id.list, records);
        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
```

To this:

```
   @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        int num = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
        records = dao.getAllRecords();
        mAdapter = new TimetableAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.id.list, records);
        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean don't have a list in my XML? I thought <ListView> was that?

Comment: Yeah, I've been reading the documentation and I'll be honest, I am kind of confused about how to include a list in my document as a fragment, some guides have had the <fragment> tags in their XML in place of <TextView>

Comment: OK, so the MainActivity, when initially opened, the fragment it is containing is CourseList?

Comment: Yes, the fragment is CourseList

Comment: Did you try it with `onViewCreated`?

Comment: Starting the emulator as we speak

Comment: Have you retrieved information from `dao` successfully? Your code looks fine, I am thinking maybe something is happening in your parse. So add a log somewhere to verify that you are actually receiving it all correctly. Like in your adapter. Add a `Log.d("Course", rowItem.getCourse()+"")`;

Comment: I'll check that when I get my emulator working again, it's doing some weird things just now

Comment: I included the Log.d("Course", rowItem.getCourse()+"") in the adapter, it doesn't seem to return anything, so perhapse not reaching that part of the code